# 2008 Pontiac Vibe

Tags: cooling-system, overheating

I replaced my thermostat a week ago and it’s been fine now there’s no heat and my temperature goes up and down my heat will work for a minute or two then back cold do I need a water pump or what

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like the coolant system wasn't bled properly ... you need to get all of the air out of the system.

Comment: I bled my cooling system and it is still no heat and my temperature is still rising

Answer (score 1):

As already said, these are classci signs of air in the system-suggest bleeding again

Comment: Find instructions for this type of engine — you don't tell us what it is — and follow them. Some motors have non-obvious bleeding routines.

Comment: 1.8liter 4 cylinder

Comment: 1.8liter 4 cylinder